# ffmpeg libcdio input device under windows

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, cd-rom

I'd like to use the ffmpeg tools for cd stuff under windows, however I was unable to provide working -i parameter (My CD Drive is F:\; I tried F:\ and F:\Track01.cda):
`[libcdio @ 043fe2a0] Could not open drive F:\
[libcdio @ 0635c2e0] Could not open drive F:\Track01.cda`
Does anyone know what to use as -i parameter under windows with libcdio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just noticed you have to write `F:` `F:\`